# reactjs: css transition time for adding/removing components

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I will have some kind of list as a component, which will change in size, depending on how many children it has at the moment. Unfortunately, this makes said list jump around quite violently.
Adding `transition: 'all 0.3s ease'` doesn't help of course, since the number of children doesn't affect a component's style but only the grid. However, I thought I was smarter than that and hack it into the styles either way:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div
            style={{
                width: Object.values(this.props.children).reduce((a,b) => a?.props?.width + b?.props?.width),
                transition: 'all 0.3s ease',
                ...this.props.style
            }}
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Seems I thought wrong. The calculated width produces the right result, but the transition delay is still missing. Any ideas why?

Also: is there another (actually working) way to implement a smooth transition when adding / removing children from a component?

Comment: Could you provide a visual demo or sketch of the desired result? I am having a hard time imaging how this growth in width is reflected visually from your example, other than having a new child element appear An idea, perhaps you could animate the child element's width using `@keyframes` so their width grows gradually and thus does the parent component's

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone who faces the same issue: I solved it!
There's probably a way to make the parent of the resizing component be aware of what the size is supposed to be. Then calculate the resizing component's size from within the parent and hand it down to the resizing component's styles from there. That's it.